# Magento 2 Add custom tab to product details page conditionally

Tags: magento2, products, ajax, tabs

I have added code for adding tab in `app\code\Store\Nutrition\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml`.

```
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
          <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">                            
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="nutrition" as="nutrition" template="Store_Nutrition::product/view/nutrition.phtml" group="detailed_info" after="additional">
             <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Nutrition Facts</argument>                
             </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
        <move element="nutrition.tab" destination="product.info.details" after="additional"/>        
    </body>
</page>
```

On click of the tab an ajax request is sent which then fetches the data and displays in the tab. If the response is null the text is displayed as "No Data to display!"

Now if the response is null I do not want to display the tab.

I know I'll have to send the ajax request on some other event like page load or document ready so that I can get the response beforehand. However I don't know how to display or hide tab based on response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a tab in product detail, `Magento` itself create `div` with `id` like `tab-label-tab-as-parameter-name`.  In your case Magento create a tab id like `tab-label-nutrition` and for tab content `Magento` create an `div` with `id` `tab-as-parameter-name`. In your case `nutrition` is `id` , so you can achieve it by,

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: YOUR_URL,
    data: YOUR_DATA,
    success: function (data) {
        if(data.result==NULL){
            jQuery('#tab-label-nutrition').hide();
            jQuery('#nutrition').hide();
        }
    },
});
```

For that in your `controller` you need to send the response as `JSON` and you can also add some effect for hiding the tab.

Comment: Somehow I am facing some issues. I am not sure if this code is the root cause. When I hit the product page and click on any of the tab(product description, more information or nutrition facts), the click does not trigger. I mean the hide/show does not work. Can you help?